# Obtaining Values from UIImage Array and Converting to String

Tags: arrays, swift, string, xcode, uiimage

Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'String'

I am trying to create a book, and if I type in the name of the picture I want in the UIImageView constructor which is "cup", my program executes correctly and displays the same picture on every page. If I try and do "imageNames[element]" to get all my pictures displayed depending on page within my for loop it says it can not convert UIImage to String

```
      var imageNames: [UIImage] = [
         UIImage(named: "open")!,
         UIImage(named: "cup")!
      ]




        for element in 0 ..< imageNames.count {

        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = randomColor()

        //Where error is occurring!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: 
        imageNames[element]))
        vc.view.addSubview(imageView)
        }
```

I would think that imageNames[element] would give me the String value in the array. 
My goal is that when I open the book.... "open" picture is on the first page, and "cup" picture is on the second page.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array of strings rather than images

```
 let imageNames = ["open", "cup"]

 for imageName in imageNames { // no reason for an index based loop

    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = randomColor()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName))
    vc.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Or if you really want an array of images

```
 let images = [
     UIImage(named: "open")!,
     UIImage(named: "cup")!
 ]

 for image in images { // no reason for an index based loop

    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = randomColor()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    vc.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: Wow I thought I did that already, I have been on this for at least 2 hours. That is exactly what I needed though. Appreciate it!